# Mouse enter and mouse leave events doesn't work with mouse move event

Tags: javascript, css, mouseenter, mouseleave, mouse-cursor

I'm trying to create a custom cursor and detect the hover on some elements but the mouse enter and mouse leave event doesn't work properly when I uncomment the 2 lines in the mouse move event.
However, It works when I delete the transform property of my cursor for an unkown reason.

I tried to subtract the half of the size of my cursor in my mouse move event, instead of having the transform property but I have the same result.

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
const elHover = document.querySelectorAll("img");

let mouse = {
  x: undefined,
  y: undefined,
};

document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  mouse.x = e.pageX;
  mouse.y = e.pageY;
  // cursor.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
  // cursor.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
});

elHover.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
    // console.log("enter");
    document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  });

  element.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
    // console.log("leave");
    document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #1d3557;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande",
    "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.cursor {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px white solid;
  z-index: 999;

  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
 <div class="gallery">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" />
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="cursor"></div>
```

Comment: Your snippet seem to be working well

Comment: Yes it's beacause the two lines whose I'm talking about are commented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `pointer-events:none` to `cursor` element's css.

> The pointer-events property allows for control over how HTML elements
> respond to mouse/touch events – including CSS hover/active states,
> click/tap events in Javascript, and whether or not the cursor is
> visible.
>
> the prime use case for pointer-events is to allow click or tap
> behavior to “pass through” an element to another element below it on
> the Z axis.

Source - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/